# nginx php-fpm how to disable log warnings?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, log-files, fastcgi

I've a setup with nginx + php-fpm. I found in my nginx error log a lot of PHP Warning messages like this:

```
2016/03/17 20:57:23 [error] 23002#0: *114868 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Declaration of Walker_Category_Filter::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker_Category::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0) in /var/www/wp-content/themes/venture/functions/theme/custom-post-types.php on line 0
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3464", client: 52.69.241.233, server: www.myhost.net, request: "GET /appuntamenti/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.myhost.net"
```

I don't want to log event like this, they fill up my logs and create a lot of rumors on New Relic reports.
Do you knwow ho to change this behavior of nginx?

I've tried to change my php.ini configuration with this:

```
 error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
```

The event are logged in nginx error log, so I think that's not related to php-fpm configuration.

Any suggestion is welcome

Thanks
Fabio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are warnings generated by PHP itself; since they're printed to stdout (or maybe stderr) without being caught, they end up in your server logs.

I would expect that entry in your `php.ini` to be sufficient to silence those warnings.  If that is not happening, you should check to see if the application overrides those settings through [the `error_reporting()` function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

In general, you should pay attention to warnings - they are warnings after all!  Whoever is responsible for maintaining the application (that might be you) should look into them and fix them; silencing them in your logs is just papering over the issues, and may come back to bite you in the ass.

Comment: You were right! There was an:
    error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERAB
LE_ERROR );
in wp-load.php

I'm aware that warning should be not ignored, but I'm using WordPress and it's not easy to investigate on third party application. Probably there are some incompatibilities with PHP7.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Although Xiong's answer worked for you, I had to use the following method.

After editing PHP.ini files and ensuring no ini_set/error_reporting values and restarting php5-fpm service I was still getting Warnings appeared in the end I had to add this to my fpm pool file

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

to turn off warnings:

```
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

then restart service

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: Yes apparently in php-land any random code you allow to run can change the logging setting and override whatever you configured.  This admin setting prevents code from overriding your preferred logging setting, and so is the right approach for a sysadmin type running an app that wants to control logging (vs app developer).

Answer (score 1):

nginx add

```
location / {
    ...

    fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED";
    
    ...
}
```